# Show that det A is even.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph with no perfect matching and let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$. Show that $\det(A)$ is even.

Ref: "Graphs and Matrices" by R. B. Bapat.

Answer (score 2):

The [permanent of $A$ counts the number of perfect matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent#Perfect_matchings).  So if $G$ has no perfect matching then $\text{perm}(A)=0$. Moreover, the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Definition) and the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent#Definition) of a matrix are congruent modulo $2$:
$$\text{perm}(A)= \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_{n}} \prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i),i}\equiv
\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma )\prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i),i}=\det(A)\pmod{2}.$$
Hence
$$\det(A)\equiv \text{perm}(A)=0\pmod{2}$$
that is $\det(A)$ is an even number.

Comment: can you tell me what it means by graph with no perfect matching?

Comment: What do you mean?